# Toggl desktop app has an empty black user interface

Tags: windows-10

The Toggl desktop application starts but has an empty black user interface. There is an icon in the Taskbar but that is it. What have we tried?

- When we hover over the Taskbar icon, the app preview is an empty black rectangle.
- When we <kbd>Alt + Tab</kbd>, Toggl is there but as an empty black rectangle.
- We have looked in the Windows error logs and found no associated errors.
- We have also uninstalled and reinstalled Toggl. Same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked. Thank you to @toggl support on Twitter. :)

- Uninstall Toggl.
- Delete `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\TogglDesktop`
- Reinstall Toggl from https://support.toggl.com/category/desktopapp